# How to convert incoming buffer data from serial port to nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

hello I'am using Arduino and node js 
I sent and recive data but the data incoming from arduino like this :

```
 <Buffer 00 00 00 e0 e0 e0 00 e0 e0 e0>

<Buffer e0 e0 e0 e0 00 e0 e0 00 e0 00 e0 e0 e0>
```

How can i decode this to  UTF8

arduino

```
int incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps

}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0) {

incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:

Serial.print(incomingByte); 

}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`readable.setEncoding`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) method from Node SerialPort class:

```
const SerialPort =  require('serialport');

var port = new SerialPort("COM3").setEncoding('utf8');
```

Comment: thanks  @heltonbiker- I tried to modify this value to utilize `utf8`, `ascii`, and `hex` with no luck. I imagine there might be some work I need to do on the C++ library side to get things in the right format, or at least to understand how it is sending data. It does say it supports SPI.

Answer (score 2):

In node.js you can use [`toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end):

```
console.log(incomeBuffer.toString('utf8'))
```

Comment: console.log(incomeBuffer.toString('utf8')) not working

Answer (score 1):

`incomingByte.toString()`

> encoding  The character encoding to decode to. Default: 'utf8'

look at [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Buffer class to do various conversions to get printable hex data.

```
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const { Buffer } = require('buffer')

let buffer = []
port.on('data', function (data) {
    buffer.push(Buffer.from(data, 'ascii'))
}})

// Button handler or something else
let buffer_ascii = ''
buffer.forEach(chunk => {
    buffer_ascii += chunk.toString('hex') 
})
console.log(buffer_ascii)
```